# How to add the focus to nvd3 charts in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-nvd3

I have to build a web app which is data driven, So I will have to use so many chart types from nvd3, there are some charts in nvd3 where the Focus is added.
But I will need to add the focus for every chart.

Is there any way to do that in angualr????????

Comment: _But I will need to add the focus for every chart._ Only one element can have focus at a time.  It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.